# Running remote_console of an erlang release via ssh works weird

Tags: ssh, erlang, elixir

I'm running the erlang release of my elixir app via `systemd` on EC2 ubuntu.
When I tried to run `remote_console` of my app via ssh, it works weird.

```
# Good way. Connect to EC2 and run remote_console

$ ssh ubuntu@<ip>
$ sudo myapp remote_console
iex(myapp@127.0.0.1)> Application.started_applications()
... # All of my applications. OK.


# Bad way. Run remote_console via ssh command

$ ssh ubuntu@<ip> sudo myapp remote_console
iex(remshce50beca-myapp@127.0.0.1)> Application.started_applications()
[{:logger, 'logger', '1.4.1'}, {:iex, 'iex', '1.4.1'},
 {:elixir, 'elixir', '1.4.1'}, {:compiler, 'ERTS  CXC 138 10', '7.0.4'},
 {:stdlib, 'ERTS  CXC 138 10', '3.3'}, {:kernel, 'ERTS  CXC 138 10', '5.2'}]
# Weird node name remshce50beca-myapp and only 3 applications are started.
```

I don't understand why those are different.

Comment: Try with `-t`: `ssh -t ubuntu@<ip> sudo myapp remote_console`.

Comment: And to add some context to the answer marked as duplicate, `ssh` without `-t` will not give `$TERM` any value. `-t` will force allocating a TTY and a give a valid value for `$TERM` and should work here.

Comment: @Dogbert Thanks a lot!